# Show mysql ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY violations as warnings

Tags: mysql

Doing MYSQL update, and it would be awesome if I could use the application as is, and see the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY violations as warnings, so I could test the different features one-by-one, without fixing all the queries first.
Is there a way to do this with PDO?

Comment: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY violation cannot be converted to warning. It is not execution-time problem.

Comment: Apply `EXPLAIN {query text}` - it will report either execution plan or an error without the query execution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, when you disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, then mysql is not going to generate a warning if the query broke the sql standard on group by, therefore there is no warning that PDO could capure and report.

Comment: What about the other way, leave ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in, and instead of errors allow only warnings?

Comment: If you enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY then mysql generates an error. This behaviour is not configurable.